# IndexedDB - Do I need an "id" field?

Tags: indexing, indexeddb

After reading several tutorials I still have problems understanding IndexedDB completely...
I already build a "playground-app" with it, but I have a question before continuing....

Is it recommended to have a distinct "id" field in the ObjectStores?

What happens if object at index 42 (without id-field) needs to be updated? [From what I know IndexedDB doesn't have an update command.] How would you exchange/update this object in-place without breaking the references to this objects?

When you have a id-field - How to find a unused id-value when you add a new object to an ObjectStore? Is there a clever way to do it?

I couldn't find a discussion about this on SO or somewhere else...

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an id is not required but is recommended because it simplifies writing your program. This advice applies to traditional relational databases (SQL) and indexedDB (NoSQL).

Using a simple integer counter is helpful and recommended, even when you have another property or group of properties (a composite/compound primary key) that uniquely identifies each object in a store.

indexedDB provides a way to generate 'unused' id values. Use the autoincrement flag when calling createObjectStore and setting the key path.

See the [MDB documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB) to learn more. Specifically, review the section on object store keys.

In regards to the 42 question, you can [open a cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore.openCursor), then [advance the cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor.advance) by 42, and then retrieve the value, change its properties, and then, if the underlying transaction is in readwrite mode, you can call [cursor.update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor.update) to replace the object at the cursor's position. Using this technique is not recommended primarily because it is not practical and can be confusing. It is preferable to use a simple auto-incremented integer id, especially when you are just learning.

It does not matter what the name of the property that represents the key is, so long as it conforms to normal JavaScript object property naming rules, and you access it consistently.